# Change Undefined to Empty String

Tags: javascript, exif-js

I'm using exif.js to pull metadata from images I upload to a CMS. When images do not have meta data, some values return "undefined". What I would like to do is change this "undefined" value to an empty string using something like this: (Credit: Stanley below)

```html
   // not set var i means
// i === undefined

var j = (typeof (i) !== 'undefined' ? i : 'not found');

console.log(j); // 'not found'
```

Yet, After a few hours looking at the code, I still cannot figure out how exif.js is returning the undefined value so that I can change it to an empty string.

Link to exif.js: https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js/blob/master/exif.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

You can simply use `if`statements in the `.getData` function around your variables to not allow the undefined to run in the EXIF.JS library. Note this code is usually written in the script on your page if you are following the examples on EXIF.JS Github.

```html
  EXIF.getData(img, function() {
                var model = EXIF.getTag(this, "Model");
                
                if (model) {
                  var modelDataSpan = document.getElementById('model-'+id);
                  modelDataSpan.innerHTML = `${model}`;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

`var i = "undefined";`

you've set a string to `var i` so this cannot test is it undefined.

you can use `typeof (i) !== 'undefined'` to check a var type and check isn't 'undefined', then use Short Circuit Operators to return the value

e.g.

```
// not set var i means
// i === undefined

var j = (typeof (i) !== 'undefined' ? i : 'not found');

console.log(j); // 'not found'
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/01mgmyng/1/)

Comment: I think I understand how to use this properly now. Thanks! Yet, I'm still struggling to find the right variable to use this on within exif.js. I'll keep trying and let you know if I figure it out.